# Excluding library class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build

Is there a way to exclude classes getting built from a specific Eclipse project's referenced library?

I'm aware of `Build Path` -> `Exclude`, though I'd like a more *project specific* setting, to avoid building unnecessary classes. **That is, some projects should be able to access the library's files, while some exclude it from their build path.** The library has the source file attached, so I'm able to edit and exclude all classes from the library in Eclipse.

Comment: [Skip some file during compilation Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761504/skip-some-file-during-compilation-eclipse) ?

Comment: I meant to emphasize that I've already tried that, and that it's not a very project specific way to go. Only some projects should exclude a specific file from being built.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Ah, yes. Marked my own answer as acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a possible solution. I linked my library's source via `Build Path` -> `Link Source`, and then excluded the files from that source folder.